# Unexpected 'x' character is displaying at the beginning of HTML document

Tags: php, regex, encoding, utf-8, notepad++

See source code of http://dev.piatanoua.md/, the first character.

So, we have our closed-source project. There were a lot of whitespaces and tabs, and here is what I have done to fix this problem:

1. In Windows (Just.. nm) searched for *.php files in project using Windows Explorer
2. Opened them in Notepad++. Encoding was automatically set to UTF-8 without BOM
3. Searched and replaced `[ |   ]+$` to `NULL`.
4. Saved all files (there is a special button for it)
5. Uploaded to Bitbucket
6. Cloned `develop` branch at our development server
7. Used `cp -f` to copy modified files to nginx directory

**Another problem appeared.** `'x'` character is displaying at the beginning of each HTML document. Source code seems to be OK — no `'x'` is marked for output.
Our another software engineer said that problem might be in Notepad++'s encoding settings, he said I need to restore BOM. Is that right? What are other ways to fix that?

Any help is appreciated.